# How do I Install drivers for my motherboard?

Tags: drivers, ethernet, motherboard

So I have the Gigabyte B550 Aorus Elite AX V2 in my new build. It works fine and drivers work great on windows (dual boot system)
But how I notice it says on the website I need to get Linux driver's from 3rd party vendors? So where would that be from ?
My RJ45 port is running much slower than intended.

Comment: You mostly don't - everything you need is included in the kernel. What problems do you see with your ethernet port?

Comment: on the speed test website it gives a result of 1mb down and 0.3 up 
i am on unlimited Data from smarty. that is pluged in to a Deco and that is connected to the board via a SFTP gold plated Cat8 LAN cable.

Comment: your saying the Gigabyte B550 Aorus Elite AX V2 motherboard is shit ?
The deciding factor on that was that it had 2.5Gigabit Ethernet and supports wifi6.
Im not a gamer anyway

Comment: Smarty is a mobile network. 1mbit/0.3mbit might not be that bad depending on your location and network congestion. Try retesting it on a home broadband connection. I think that @vidarlo might have been referring to is that often integrated NIC chipsets can be of lower quality than a dedicated network card but this is less of a problem than it used to be

Comment: @moo They advertise it as a NIC with bandwidth control, which typically means it's a complete and utter piece of crap...

Comment: The smarty sim is in a deco router the computer itself detects it as 1000mb/s
On the windows boot on the same computer it is fine I get 2Gb on the Ethernet.

Comment: I am only paying for unlimited data from smarty. Specifically for the purpose of having 2.5Gb internet. Also  I am not allowed to have any work done on the building where I live So I can not get Toob installed it was really the only option I had available.unlimited data for lowest price.
Is it possable that deco is incompatable with ubuntu ? 
I updated the Bios firmware before installing windows and that was before I had Ubuntu to install.
Windows and Ubuntu are both on the same M.2 NMvE could it becreating a driver conflict or a kernal conflict since windows runs on the linux kernal?